# Moving WPF controls in design UI

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am new to WPF, and this may sound like a stupid question, but I just can't move my control in my UI somehow. I thought I could move the control like I did in WinForm, but it does nothing.

[image]

I added a simple button, and clicked it & tried to drag it to another position, but the mouse only forms a dotted square doing nothing to the button, only invalidating the focus. What am I doing wrong?

Btw, I know how to use the `properties > layout` to set the position. I'm just wondering if I can do it at the design tab with drag & drop.

Comment: I recommend you not to use WPF designer since it has a lot of issues when you work on something bigger than Hello, World. XAML gives you full control over UI development.

Comment: @Maxim yeah I know. I'm working on my hello world that's why. thanks anyway!

Comment: For me it worked after I set the `margin` attribute of `Button` tag in XAML designer like `Margin="10"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I mistakenly deleted `<Grid>` tag.

A dumb self Q&A, but I'll just leave it here in case somebody wonders..